# List schema.xml, change newform.aspx to custom layouts file

Tags: schema

I have created 'myUI.aspx' file @  /_layouts/myproject/myUI.aspx. This application page(aka LayoutPageBase) is used as a dialog across the farm just for creating new items in my list. As such I would also like to set it as the template for adding list items.

My custom list has a schema defenition where at the bottom I find

```
  <Forms>
           <Form Type='DisplayForm' Url='DisplayForm.aspx' SetupPath='pages\form.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
           <Form Type='EditForm' Url='EditForm.aspx' SetupPath='pages\form.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
           <Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' SetupPath='pages\form.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
  </Forms>
```

Both the List definition & the layout file are in the same solution.

I have tried changing NewForm to each of the below:

```
  <Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' SetupPath='_layouts\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' /> 

  <Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' Path='_layouts\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' /> 

  <Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' Path='layouts\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
```

Is there a way to do this or am I using the wrong kind of .aspx file?

Comment: Try `<Form Type='NewForm' Url='_layouts\myproject\myUI.aspx'`

Comment: I tried this before. It looks like the url attribute should only contains the file name, which the list form will get. Entering a path results in error _Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name._

Comment: so how did you manage to set it for creating new items? did you try to create a new list from that shema, maybe the existing list doesn't get the upgrade ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After analyse the trace logs, I found the solution (for my case).

The content of attribute Path is **relative to the installation path of the feature**, e.g.

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\myproject\MyListInstanceName\

The content of attribute Path is **relative to the template path**, e.g.

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\

So with

```
 <Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' Path='_layouts\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
```

Sharepoint tried to load the file **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\_layouts\myproject\myUI.aspx** which does not exist.

**So the solution for your code is:**

```
<Forms>
    <Form Type='DisplayForm' Url='DisplayForm.aspx' Path='LAYOUTS\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
    <Form Type='EditForm' Url='EditForm.aspx' Path='LAYOUTS\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
    <Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' Path='LAYOUTS\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
  </Forms>
```

This means your last try must have been worked!

What was your error message? Did you look to the TraceLog, which file SharePoint tries to load?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using 15 hive in path?

```
<Form Type='NewForm' Url='NewForm.aspx' Path='_layouts\15\myproject\myUI.aspx' WebPartZoneID='Main' />
```

Comment: Yep, I tried it. This did not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

look at these links which explain how to do this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223431/Custom-SharePoint-List-Forms

http://thesharepointdive.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/list-forms-deployment-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1-of-4/

these applications are in SharePoint 2010 but works in SharePoint 2013, I tried it and it works.

I hope you find it useful.